# Is it possible to change USB Audio Interface input stereo to mono?

Tags: usb, audio, streaming

Is it possible to change USB Audio Interface input stereo to mono?
So we're streaming using a **mixer** to **audio interface** to **phone** via **USB OTG**.

The thing with the Audio Interface, and btw our Audio Interface is the Behringer UMC22, and the Interface treats its input 1 as the left channel and the input 2 as right channel. Now so when we stream, it only outputs on the left channel because that is where our mixer is plugged in (input 1).

Is there like an app or anything that I can do to let the recording input just like in PC to change from 2 channels (stereo) to 1 Channel (mono) only? Thank you

Comment: What about a hardware solution using an Y-cable so that you can plug in your mixer into both channels?

Comment: Oooh thank you. We just got our first audio interface so I didn't know the interface would do that. Hahaha I should have made our 10m TRS Cable stereo on one end and two mono on the other. Thank you for this solution.